# Number of monotone functions on a square grid

Tags: co.combinatorics

How many monotone mappings $[n] \times [n] \to [n]$ exist? Here:

- $[n]$ denotes $\{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$,
- Monotone means that if $x_1 \le x_2$ and $y_1 \le y_2$, then $f(x_1, y_1) \le f(x_2, y_2)$.

I'm interested in the answer up to $2^{\Theta(\cdot)}$-notation. To give an example, I would be absolutely happy if the answer is $2^{\Theta(n \log n)}$, while $2^{\Theta(n^2)}$ would kill my idea.
Anything strictly less than $2^{\Theta(n^2)}$ would be an improvement for me, but I would like an upper bound with a quasi-linear exponent (if it exists, of course).

If we instead consider monotone $[n] \to [n]$, then the number of mappings is around $\binom{2n-1}{n}$ (we can think of it as $2n - 1$ balls, where $n$ balls represent the numbers $1, \ldots, n$, and remaining $n-1$ balls represent positions where the function value increases by $1$).
I've tried to apply this idea to the $[n]^2 \to n$, but I failed to utilize monotonicity on *both* arguments, and could only get $n^{O(n^2)}$.

The answer for $[n]^2 \to [n]$ is clearly between $n^{\Theta(n)}$ (we get this much even for $[n] \to [n]$) and $n^{n^2}$ (it's the number of all possible functions $[n]^2 \to [n]$).

I'm also interested in the same question for mapping $[n]^d \to [n]$, where $d \in \mathbb N$ (and, in computer science terms, $d$ is *not* a fixed parameter).

[Dedekind numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_number) answer the question for monotone boolean functions, which can be thought of as $[2]^d \to [2]$.

P.S.: No idea which tags to use.

Comment: In the combinatorics literature, these sorts of maps are frequently studied as _(reverse) plane partitions_ and _(reverse) P-partitions_.

Comment: In this case, a reverse plane partition with part size $\leq n$ is a map $\phi: [n]\times[n] \to [n]$ satisfying $\phi(a,b) \leq \phi(c,d)$  iff $a \leq c$ and $b \leq d$, so the number of such provides is the quantity you're looking for. [MacMahon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_partition) gave a product formula that counts them.

Comment: Thank you! Using the expression from https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PlanePartition.html, the answer is $2^{\Theta(n^2)}$.

Comment: Have the numbers been tabulated at oeis.org ?

Comment: @GerryMyerson: looks like they're sequence [A008793](https://oeis.org/A008793)

Comment: @Alex, I don't think so. I get $1,6,175$ for $n=1,2,3$.

Comment: Technically these are plane partitions whose 3D representation as a stacking of boxes fits inside of a $n \times n \times (n-1)$ box. This explains the discrepancy with the OEIS link above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to [Alex Lazar](https://mathoverflow.net/users/128452/alex-lazar) for referring me to the right keywords.

This is called something like "the number of [plane partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_partition) that fit inside the $n \times n \times n$ box", and [can be computed as](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PlanePartition.html) :
$$
PL(n,n,n)=\frac{G^3(n+1) \cdot G(3n+1)}{G^3(2n+1)},
$$
where $G$ is the [Barnes G-function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barnes_G-function). Mathematica tells me that the highest-order term in the Taylor expansion of its natural logarithm is
$$\frac 32 (3 \ln 3 - 4 \ln 2) n^2 \approx 0.785 n^2.$$
So the answer to my question is $2^{\Theta(n^2)}$.

Comment: Please accept your answer so the question gets listed as accepted.

Comment: @JoshuaZ, it said that I can do this in 2 days.